# NPE when encrypting fields for SQLServer databases using debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium to do a CDC from SQLServer to kafka, and as per the business needs, some of the columns must be encrypted.

For the environment POV, I have 2 kafka-connect instances running on K8S, and I have in total around 50 connectors running that stream data from SQL-Server to Kafka.

Here is the snippet of the connector json file

```
{
"name": "live.sql.users",
...
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "drop",
        "transforms": "unwrap,cipher",
        "predicates.isTombstone.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.cipher.predicate": "isTombstone",
        "transforms.cipher.negate": "true",
        "transforms.cipher.cipher_data_keys": "[ { \"identifier\": \"my-key\", \"material\": { \"primaryKeyId\": 1000000001, \"key\": [ { \"keyData\": { \"typeUrl\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey\", \"value\": \"GhDLeulEJRDC8/19NMUXqw2jK\", \"keyMaterialType\": \"SYMMETRIC\" }, \"status\": \"ENABLED\", \"keyId\": 2000000002, \"outputPrefixType\": \"TINK\" } ] } } ]",
        "transforms.cipher.type": "com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.CipherField$Value",
        "transforms.cipher.cipher_mode": "ENCRYPT",
        "predicates": "isTombstone",
        "transforms.cipher.field_config": "[{\"name\":\"Password\"},{\"name\":\"MobNumber\"}, {\"name\":\"UserName\"}]",
        "transforms.cipher.cipher_data_key_identifier": "my-key"
...
}
```

and when I applied it, after few seconds I got the below error, when I call the /connectors/<connector_name>/status api

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:346)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:261)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:191)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:240)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\t
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: error: ENCRYPT of field path 'UserName' having data 'deleted605' failed unexpectedly\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.RecordHandler.processField(RecordHandler.java:90)\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.SchemaawareRecordHandler.lambda$matchFields$0(SchemaawareRecordHandler.java:73)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.SchemaawareRecordHandler.matchFields(SchemaawareRecordHandler.java:50)\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.CipherField.processWithSchema(CipherField.java:163)\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.CipherField.apply(CipherField.java:140)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.PredicatedTransformation.apply(PredicatedTransformation.java:56)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t
... 11 more\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\t
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultGenerics.nextGenericTypes(DefaultGenerics.java:77)\n\t
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.pushTypeVariables(FieldSerializer.java:144)\n\t
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:102)\n\t
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:627)\n\t
at com.github.hpgrahsl.kafka.connect.transforms.kryptonite.RecordHandler.processField(RecordHandler.java:75)\n\t
... 21 more\n
```

Knowing that, the same configs working with other connectors with no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further debugging and looking into Kryo library, it ends up that `Kryo` class is not thread-safe, as per Kryo the [documentation](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#thread-safety):

> Kryo is not thread safe. Each thread should have its own Kryo, Input, and Output instances.

I opened a thread on kryptonite repo, and it has been confirmed from the main committer that it doesn't support multi threads and the only way to do this is to have separate connector instance or pooling ([the full thread](https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kryptonite-for-kafka/issues/8#issuecomment-1432876625)), which is not feasible as I have more than 50 connectors running in the same time.

Regarding the pooling option of Kryo Instance, [here is guide on how to do it](https://mykidong.medium.com/howto-pool-kryo-instances-in-multithreaded-environment-97e34adf5f5e), yet I didn't try it out.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem or will face it in future.

[Update]

Now kryptonite-for-kafka support the pooling option for kryo Instance, thanks to [Hans](https://github.com/hpgrahsl) for the quick turnaround, I tested the change and working fine for 4 consecutive days.